# Modeling Products in an ecommerce Database in Django

Tags: django, database, e-commerce

I'm struggling with database design for an ecommerce platform in Django.

I have a Product abstract base class, and Book, DownloadableItem and Laptop (examples) as concrete subclasses.

Each of those have specific implementations of get_price() method.

I would like to have a ForeignKey(Product), but the problem is that I cannot have a ForeignKey to an abstract base class...

Do you think django-polymorphic package would be adapted?
Are there better alternatives?
What are the pros and cons?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm confused on why you would want to have a ForeignKey to the base class? Your abstract model is just something that has the shared attributes/methods for your subclasses? There might be another option, could you explain why you're wanting to have the foreign key to the base class.

Comment: For example, a ProductImage for instance has got a ForeignKey to Product.
Cannot guess ahead of time which type is gonna be the Product (downloadableitem, book etc...)